# Did/Have you usage

Tags: grammaticality

Is this the correct way to say?

```
Did you take and come lunch box today?
```

And,

1. What is the correct way to use `Did/Have`?

Comment: Could you explain what this sentence is supposed to mean? It makes absolutely no sense to me.

Comment: what you want to say exactly.your sentence is totally wrong grammatically

Comment: do you want to ask for lunch anyone today ? then you can say "will you take lunch today with me?" or if you want to  ask they have took their lunch or not  you can ask like this "have you taken lunch?" or you can also ask shortly like this "had lunch?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Come* is not involved in this expression, it's either "Did you take lunch?" or *Have you taken lunch?."

*Did* is appropriate if you want to know whether or not someone has taken lunch.

*Have* is appropriate if you want to know whether they took their lunch previously, or plan to go later - with this, you are saying you expect him/her to go to lunch at some time.  However, you might hear/see *Did you take lunch yet?* which also means this and is not wrong.

Comment: In the U.S. at least, _Did you **have** lunch_ or _Did you **eat** lunch_ would be much more common than _Did you **take** lunch_.